# fitting the webview page in iPhone without scroll depending upon the data present in a html file

Tags: iphone

can any one help me..am doing one webview application in iPhone. I am very new to this is technology...my requirement is when am displaying the html content into the webview page depending upon the data the webview page has to fit that means no scrolling comes the page should fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code :

```
self.myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```